# Wrap text with list item and icon

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to keep the tick icon to the left and for all the text to stay in one block.

Right now, the text goes under the tick icon which doesn't look great.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/dze6wdhc/)

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check" style="padding-right:0.5em;"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lacus at eros elementum, sit amet scelerisque tortor rhoncus. Donec imperdiet magna purus, ut congue est
    sollicitudin vel. Maecenas eget blandit magna. Nulla vel faucibus neque. Nam sed mauris at eros consequat tincidunt.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `display:flex` to `li` like below.

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display:flex;
}
```

```css
li {list-style-type:none; display:flex;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul>
        <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check" style="padding-right:0.5em;"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lacus at eros elementum, sit amet scelerisque tortor rhoncus. Donec imperdiet
            magna purus, ut congue est sollicitudin vel. Maecenas eget blandit magna. Nulla vel faucibus neque. Nam sed mauris
            at eros consequat tincidunt.</li>
            
        <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check" style="padding-right:0.5em;"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lacus at eros elementum, sit amet scelerisque tortor rhoncus. Donec imperdiet
            magna purus, ut congue est sollicitudin vel. Maecenas eget blandit magna. Nulla vel faucibus neque. Nam sed mauris
            at eros consequat tincidunt.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```css
li {
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:25px;
}
li:before{
  content: "";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  left:0;
  top:2px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lacus at eros elementum, sit amet scelerisque tortor rhoncus. Donec imperdiet magna purus, ut congue est sollicitudin vel. Maecenas eget blandit magna. Nulla vel faucibus neque. Nam sed mauris at eros consequat tincidunt.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `text-indent` property. Set a negative value equal to the space occupied by the icon.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-indent: -12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check" style="padding-right:0.5em;"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lacus at eros elementum, sit amet scelerisque tortor rhoncus. Donec imperdiet magna purus, ut congue est
    sollicitudin vel. Maecenas eget blandit magna. Nulla vel faucibus neque. Nam sed mauris at eros consequat tincidunt.</li>
      <li><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check" style="padding-right:0.5em;"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lacus at eros elementum, sit amet scelerisque tortor rhoncus. Donec imperdiet magna purus, ut congue est
    sollicitudin vel. Maecenas eget blandit magna. Nulla vel faucibus neque. Nam sed mauris at eros consequat tincidunt.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="
    position: absolute;
    display: initial;
">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tincidunt lacus at eros elementum, sit amet scelerisque tortor rhoncus. Donec imperdiet magna purus, ut congue est
    sollicitudin vel. Maecenas eget blandit magna. Nulla vel faucibus neque. Nam sed mauris at eros consequat tincidunt.</div>
```